# How to Send More Than One Argument in java soap based web services

Tags: java, web-services

**Hello i am creating a webservice in java using eclipse ide my server code is looking like below and also my client code when i called a method using single parameter in method it return the right result but when i am trying to call a method using two parameter, it return first parameter right and the second parameter value is null what is the solution as i am new in web service**

```
package cris;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class RequestHandler {
@WebMethod
public String test(String str)
{
return "Hello"+str;
}
@WebMethod
public int add1() {
    int a=5;
    int b=6;
    int c=a+b;
    return c;
}
@WebMethod
public String test1(String str1,String str2) {
    return str1+"and"+str2;
}

}
```

i generate wsdl file using eclipse ide and create a new client using same ide

```
package cris;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public class ClientTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    RequestHandlerProxy req=new RequestHandlerProxy();


    try {

        String r = req.test("anil");
        System.out.println(r);
        int res=req.add1();
        System.out.println(res);
        String res1=req.test1("anil","sahu");
        System.out.println(res1);

    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

***and my output is***

**Helloanil
11
anilandnull**

Comment: For testing Webservices you can use client like SOAP UI, which is a client tool.

Comment: is this tool is free or paid

Comment: It was free when I used, you can search on google. If this paid, I am sure there will be many other free SOAP client.

Comment: sorry to say you but are you sure that we can send more then one parameter by the following method used by me is it right because one of my boss told me that we can't pass more then one parameter in this if we want to send then we have to pass the json object so plz confirm